# A nifty tool for checking whether the expected Hadoop processes are running is jps :: PROBLEM

Tags: 13.04, hadoop

hadoopz@ubuntu:/usr/local/hadoop$ jps

The program 'jps' can be found in the following packages:

- openjdk-7-jdk
- openjdk-6-jdk

Ask your administrator to install one of them

When I check jps for Hadoop, I am getting the above result....

Comment: Multiple issues here: 1. Do you have java installed? 2. If yes, how did you install java? If no, you need to install it first. 3. Do you have superuser permissions to install? 4. You are using an EOF ubuntu, any specific reasons for that? 5. Please tell what have you tried before posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a Hadoop problem; you just have to put the jps executable into your path or create an alias for jps. The location of the jps executable is somewhere under the `/usr/lib/jvm` directory. To find the location of the jps executable browse to the `/usr/lib/jvm` directory and search for *jps* from there.

First you have to install openjdk-6-jdk. (If you want to install openjdk-7-jdk read the last paragraph.) Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk
```

Next make an alias for the jps executable. Example of a command to create an alias for jps:

```
alias jps='/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/bin/jps'
```

If you want to install openjdk-7-jdk instead of openjdk-6-jdk, you can still use the preceding two commands by substituting the string `openjdk-7-jdk` for `openjdk-6-jdk`